# SESSION and jquery menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery menu and session of user.
I have a menu in jQuery and one choice of this menu is "Login", under this when you mouseover, open a submenu with "Login " and "register a new account".
Now I want to change the "login" voice in "Logout".
I tried with this code :

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/1.gif" alt=""/>
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
            <span class="sdt_link">Login</span>
            <span class="sdt_descr">Enter or register an account</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div class="sdt_box">
        <?php  
            session_start(); 
            if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                print("<A HREF=\"login.php?logout=1\">login</A>");
            } else { 
                print("<A HREF=\"login.php?logout=1\">logout</A>");
            } 
        ?>
        <a href="#">Register an new account</a>         
    </div>
</li>
```

This code doesn't work for me because the menu is not animated any longer, but static and it doesn't work.

Then if there is a session it must show me " logout" else show me " login". Can you help me?

EDIT: this is Login2.php ( where session start or not if the username and password are right) , in the login1 tjere is only html form.

```
    <?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","ascent");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("utenti", $con);
$sql="SELECT username, password FROM utenti where username='$_POST[username]' and password='$_POST[password]'
union
select username, password from aziende where username='$_POST[username]' and password='$_POST[password]'";
$risultato=mysql_query($sql);
$prova=mysql_num_rows($risultato);
if($prova==1){
$_SESSION['username'] = 1;
header("location: lavori.php");
echo "Login effettuato con successo";
}
else {
echo "Dati incorretti";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the frist 2 rows of the page are

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

EDIT:EDIT: I RESOLVED THE PROBLEM FINALLY!

```
 <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
                {
                        echo'<a href="login.html">Esegui l accesso</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo'<a href="logout.php">Esegui il logout</a>';
                }
                ?>
```

The problem was in ECHO, i use (" "), but for output html code we must use ' '

Comment: If `session_start()` is not working, it might mean cookies are disabled in your server

Comment: try a `print_r($_SESSION);` to see if the session gets set in the first place.

Comment: you say menu is not animated. Do you see the 'login' and 'logout' links properly whether you are logged in or not?

Comment: no because i havent scripted main menu' only submenu.

Comment: Your session is not being set properly. see your login and logout link in query string both have `logout=1`. I am astonished how you decide whether to loin user or logout user?

Comment: Also share our PHP code where you are setting session

Comment: i have in the page "Login" a form where user when insert username and password start a session.

Comment: Complete fail. Your code is terrible. You don't even escape input params before putting them to SQL query. Try to read some books and the return to you attempt to create website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `session_start();` at the begining of your file.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/1.gif" alt=""/>
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
          <span class="sdt_link">Login</span>
          <span class="sdt_descr">Enter
                  or register an account</span>
          </span>
       </a>
       <div class="sdt_box">
       <?php if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
           <A HREF="login.php?logout=1">login</A>
       <?php else : ?>
           <A HREF="login.php?logout=1">logout</A>
       <?php endif; ?>
         <a href="#">Register an new account</a>         
        </div>
     </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried but it's the same thing, the menu' dont work, he remain static and dont open submenu, but if i click on main menus he link me in the page i want go. ( example : main menu index , if i click he direct me to index)